# JavaScript DOM not being read in html table

Tags: javascript, html, dom, html-table

I produce an int from JSON data

```
var f_page = ["TheHouseofMarley"];

retrieveData(f_page[0]);

function retrieveData(teamName) {               
    var baseURL = 'http://graph.facebook.com/';
    $.getJSON(baseURL+teamName+"&callback=?", function(data) {
    $('#FBlikes').append(data.likes)
        });
    };
```

and this works, it gives ~ 8407

I have a chart that reads data from < table id="chartData">

Grabbing the data from the table
I use a jQuery selector — $('#chartData td') — to select all the data cells in the table. I can then iterate through these cells with the jQuery each() method. For each cell, I determine if it's a label (e.g. "SuperWidget") or a value (e.g. "FBLike") cell, based on whether it's in the left or right column. I then store the cell contents under the 'label' or 'value' key in an associative array, which we then place inside the chartData array.

```
$('#chartData td').each( function() {
  currentCell++;
  if ( currentCell % 2 != 0 ) {
    currentRow++;
    chartData[currentRow] = [];
    chartData[currentRow]['label'] = $(this).text();
  } else {
   var value = parseFloat($(this).text());
   totalValue += value;
   value = value.toFixed(2);
   chartData[currentRow]['value'] = value;
  }

  // Store the slice index in this cell, and attach a click handler to it
  $(this).data( 'slice', currentRow );
  $(this).click( handleTableClick );
```

The problem is when I insert this number into < table id="chartData"> it is not read by the chart!

```
<table id="chartData">

<tr style="color: #0DA068">
  <td>Number of Likes </td><td><span id='FBlikes'></span> </td> //Not Read!
</tr>

<tr style="color: #194E9C">
  <td>MegaWidget</td><td>20000</td> //This is Read by the Chart!
</tr>
```

In short: Javascript output is not being read from HTML table.
Could anyone point me in some direction? I'm really new at code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually this problem occurs in Ajax.

Build a string appending "data.likes" to it. Then finally assign the string to the element.

This may sound absolutely stupid, but it worked for me. Whenever i use to build a table dynamically in jQuery using the ajax response string, i would never get a table. Then i followed the procedure I mentioned.

If my solution works, some one please help me understand why is it so.

Comment: I also forgot to initiate the chart.
I needed to add init() below the appended data